# Работа с потоками в C. Документация на русском по pthread

Tags: c, многопоточность, потоки-данных

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что нужно разобраться с работой pthread (pthread.h) в языке программирования Си.

Нашел вот в инете такую, как я понял, неплохую [статью](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). Я конечно её прочитаю, постараюсь перевести нормально, но у меня это будет медленно из-за плохого знания зыка.

А есть что-нибудь на русском, дельное, с примерами и подробно? (вообщем как обычно :) )
Кто что посоветует, если работал с этим

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сразу нашел [две](http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/threads/) [статьи](http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/threads_2/).

А вообще пробуйте читать на английском, поначалу будете понимать плохо, но со временем будете воспринимать техническую литературу также хорошо, как и на русском языке.